In HTML, is it semantically correct to include multiple dfn and abbr tags inside a summary tag and details tag?
Is this semantically correct code?:
<details>
  <summary>The <dfn><abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr></dfn> - the HyperText Markup Language standard markup language for documents designed to be displayed in a web browser.
  </summary>
  <p>This is typically used with .... </p>
</details>`

The HTML specs says that the definition for a dfn tag must be a p tag, a dl group or a section. But the same spec for the summary tag says the contents for the summary tag can be phrasing content which includes the dfn tag.
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-dfn-element

The dfn element represents the defining instance of a term. The paragraph, description list group, or section that is the nearest ancestor of the dfn element must also contain the definition(s) for the term given by the dfn element

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-summary-element

Content model:
Phrasing content, optionally intermixed with heading content.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#phrasing-content-2

a...dfn....kbd...

What if I wanted to have definitions for additional terms in the details tag, e.g.:
<details>
  <summary>The <dfn><abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr></dfn> - the HyperText Markup Language standard markup language for documents designed to be displayed in a web browser.
  </summary>
  <d>
    <dt><dfn>Term to be defined</dfn><dt>
    <dd>Explaining term to be defined.</dd> 
  <dl>
</details>`

